# How to read excel file using xmldocument

Tags: sharepoint-designer, excel, xml, openxml

I need to read the Excel data using Xmldocument.Plz help me

Comment: Sorry, this is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't.

Better use Office Open XML libraries from Microsoft.

I can't give some code but, you have to extract xlsx contents with System.IO.Packaging, find the sheet you need, and then load it in XmlDocument.

But be advised that it is quite tricky and has many caveats to do so.